# Certain public photo galleries are returning an error code

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm requesting photos using the Graph API and it works fine for some albums and not at all for others, am I missing something?

Here is one example that returns

```
"message": "Unsupported get request."
"type": "GraphMethodException"
```

https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10151179459141143.436445.588241142&type=3

Here is my call to the graph.

```
FB.api( '/' + album_id + '/photos?limit=1000', function(response)
{
});
```

This exact same all works for some album ids and not others like the one above.

I have set status to Launched and access to 13+.

Comment: For some reason it needs an access token.

Comment: But why do some work and some don't?

Comment: No idea, try submitting a bug

Comment: And adding the &access_token param didn't help.

Comment: Well, it worked for me. Submit a bug.

Comment: See my fix below, thanks for your time.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. The album id is larger than javascript integers can handle. The ID in the javascript code was 10151179459141143 but when passed to the function it passed 10151179459141144 which is weird in itself as the maximum allowed integer in javascript is a whole digit smaller than this.

Anyway, the fix was to use strings instead of numeric ids :)